# Dropbox API - permanently delete files

Tags: javascript, api, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to delete a file from Dropbox using Dropbox API? I am currently delete files this way: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#fileops-delete. However, this doesn't permanently delete files, they are just moved to trash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API doesn't expose a way to permanently delete files. (Nor does the desktop or mobile apps, for that matter. The web UI is the only way to do that.)

Comment: It seems that OneDrive API also doesn't allow to permanently delete files. All I found is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659743.aspx. And it also only moves files to Recycle Bin. What would be the reason for now allowing to do this? Security or smth? For example, Google Drive API allows permanent deletion.

Answer (score 5):

You should use : /fileops/permanently_delete 
- Permanently deletes a file or folder.

```
 OAuthUtility.PostAsync  
(
"https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/fileops/permanently_delete",
  new HttpParameterCollection
   {
      {"access_token",Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken      },
       {"root", "auto"},
        {"path", path }).Replace("\\", "/") }
    },

);
```

This endpoint is only available to Dropbox for Business apps using the X-Dropbox-Perform-As-Team-Member header.

RETURNS
An empty JSON dictionary.